# Trouble understanding the correct implementation of immutable structs?

Tags: c#, struct, immutability

I expect this is very simple, but for some reason I cannot find any clear examples of the difference between mutable and immutable structs. I have read that any struct I create should be immutable to prevent any future confusion in its use. Looking back on something I have been working on it appears I have created a mutable struct:

```
    public struct Connection 
    {
        public int x, y;
        public float strength; 

        public Connection(int x, int y, float strength)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.strength = strength;
        }
    }
```

From what I have read, to make my struct immutable it should be as follows:

```
    public struct Connection 
    {
        public readonly int x, y;
        public readonly float strength; 

        public Connection(int x, int y, float strength)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.strength = strength;
        }
    }
```

However, I became confused when reading through dotnetperls, the examples used there appear to be mutable based on what I have read.

Sorry this a newbie question. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an immutable struct, all instance fields/properties are marked readonly.  You are correct: the first example in your question is mutable, while the second is immutable.

Immutable structs provide many advantages when dealing with asynchronous/multithreaded code, but, as the name implies, their values cannot be changed.  This tends not to be a huge issue with structs, but it can be problematic when the same approach is applied to classes, which are passed by reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am too much of a new user to give you an up vote! Have it in spirit :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main situations where it is appropriate to use a structure: (1) one wants a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape; (2) one wants a small immutable object.  Without seeing how your type is used, I can't tell which situation applies.

If the purpose of a type is to act like a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape, then the former declaration is perfect in that regard, since anyone who knows anything about structure types in .NET will instantly be able to look at it and tell that it represents a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape, and will behave exactly like any other such type save only for the names and types of the encapsulated fields.

If one wishes the type to behave like an immutable object, the simplest way to achieve that is probably to declare the fields readonly.  Note that doing this won't actually make the struct immutable, since *there is no such thing as an immutable struct*. If there exists two fields somewhere defined as `Connection c1, c2;` the statement `c1=c2;` will mutate `c1` by overwriting all its fields--public and private--with the values of the corresponding fields of `c2`. The .NET framework will examine the `Connection` type only to determine the total size of all the fields; it won't care about "readonly" declarations or any other protections one might try to put on the fields.

Comment: Thank you supercat. This sheds light on things. I will be wary of using structs.


The use of the data in this case was to store that simple information in an enormous list of "Connections". The Connections are made randomly to x and y coordinates with a random strength between 0 and 1.


I would upvote you if I could :)

Comment: @AndrewScott: Whether it would be better as a struct or a class would depend upon whether you want the type to represent a radio transceiver, or a piece of information about the signal being sent or received at some moment.  Personally, I like the pattern of having a class which holds its information in an open-field struct defined in the same source file, but a lot depends on usage.